# How to set value of variable in Html element with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined a variable named "total" as the database result. And I want to show this result in the output field with id value "#total" on the interface. This id belongs to a "label" element. There can be any output element. 
Can such a situation be realized?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You talk about a database (serverside) and html (client side) and expect us to magically figure out what you do in between to get the value to the other side? Share some code man. Or better create a snippet if you can. Add some tags/description which database/server side code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set variables values into `HTML` in `jQuery` is reasonably easy.

You can use:

- `$('#myDiv').text(variable)`
- `$('#myDiv').html(variable)`

---

```js
let variable = 'Hello World';

$('#myDiv').text(variable);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah `.html()`. `$('#myDiv').html(variable);`

Comment: It's not a property of jQuery objects either. `innerHTML` is for DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var total = 300;
var total_1 =400;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
$('#total_1').html(total_1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Using JavaScript
<div id="total"></div>
<br>
Using jQuery
<div id="total_1"></div>
```